# Search function

Tags: flash, search, youtube-api

I am trying to make a youtube search api to build a flash website in my site. I want the users type keywords and find the videos from youtube and play it. I have seen tubeLoc/AS3 Wrapper. I am not sure if they are out-of-date library. Are they still good to use? Anyone has related resource or article that can provide here? Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

The [Browsing with Categories and Keywords](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_category_keyword_browsing) section of the [YouTube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started) *"explains how to retrieve a feed of all of the videos that are in a particular category or that are associated with a particular keyword"*.

Comment: You are absolutely right, this being said, not all links are born equal. This is the Google Code APIs, so this link is likely to stay live for awhile. At least, that's the thinking behind it!

Comment: :) I beefed it up a bit. Your link was actually already redirecting to a different url.